# Why is this entry in the admin history added? What does that mean?

Tags: support, moderator-tools

I have deleted [an answer I gave](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/29129/199) (the link is for 10k users) on *Drupal Answers* because it was wrong. Looking at the admin history, I find the following entry:

> Moderator deletes flag votes - from post id = 29129, count = 0

I didn't flag it; I simply deleted the answer with the "delete" button, as every user would have done.

I also checked if there were flags raised for the answer, just to be sure I missed one, but it doesn't seem the case; the moderator's menu for that answer doesn't report any flag.

[image: screenshot]

What does that entry mean? Why is it added to the admin history, if deleting own answers is not a prerogative of moderators?

Comment: That entry appears ALL THE TIME. I see it at least once for every close or deletion. I don't know what it means but I hate it.